# Script Localization doesn't work

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, array, localization, wp-localize-script

I don't get how script localization works in wordpress. 
I created an associative array in php:

```
$translations = array(
    'value1'  =>'This is first value',
    'value2'  =>'This is second value'
    );
```

I created simple javascript file where I want to use this array:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    alert(translations);
});
```

Then I try to  enqueue and localize this javascript file in my plugin like this:

```
function kvkoolitus_load_comment_validation(){
  wp_enqueue_script( 'simple-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/jquery.simple.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
  wp_localize_script( 'simple-js', 'translations', $translations );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kvkoolitus_load_comment_validation' );
```

But when I load a page with this javascript file, alert tells me that 'translations' object is null. 
What did I miss?

Comment: Where did you place `$translations = array(
    'value1'  =>'This is first value',
    'value2'  =>'This is second value'
    ); `? It should be added in the `kvkoolitus_load_comment_validation` function

Comment: Don't understand why array should by inside this function, but it works. Thanks czerspalace! Add this as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying from the answer [here regarding variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

```
Variables inside a function are only available inside that function. 
Variables outside of functions are available anywhere outside of functions, 
but not inside any function.
```

Because of that, you need to add your `$translations` array within the `kvkoolitus_load_comment_validation` function, like

```
function kvkoolitus_load_comment_validation(){
  $translations = array(
    'value1'  =>'This is first value',
    'value2'  =>'This is second value'
  ); 
  wp_enqueue_script( 'simple-js', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/jquery.simple.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
  wp_localize_script( 'simple-js', 'translations', $translations );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'kvkoolitus_load_comment_validation' );
```

Comment: I forgot about scope, damn, I need a vacation. Thanks czerspalace!